# Linux read() system call takes longer than my expectation ( serial port programming )

Tags: linux, serial-port, system-calls

I am trying to read data sent from the tty/USB0 and print it out with byte format.

Question:

1. I expect to print out the data once the reading bytes reach 40 However, the time takes much longer than I expect. The read() system call hangs and I believe the data should already be larger than 40. The data will finally be printed out but it should not take so long. Did I make anything wrong in this programming ?

thanks

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define BAUDRATE B9600            
#define MODEMDEVICE "/dev/ttyUSB0"

#define FALSE 0
#define TRUE 1

main()
{
int fd,c, res;
struct termios oldtio,newtio;
unsigned char buf[40];
fd = open(MODEMDEVICE, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY );
if (fd <0) {perror(MODEMDEVICE); exit(-1); }

tcgetattr(fd,&oldtio);
bzero(&newtio, sizeof(newtio));

newtio.c_cflag = BAUDRATE | CS8 | CLOCAL | CREAD;

newtio.c_iflag = IGNPAR | ICRNL;
newtio.c_oflag = 1;
newtio.c_lflag = ICANON;

tcflush(fd, TCIOFLUSH);
tcsetattr(fd,TCSANOW,&newtio);

int i;
while (1) {
    res = read(fd,buf,40);
    if(res==40){
        printf("res reaches 40 \n");
    }
    printf("res: %d\n",res);
    for(i=0;i<res;++i){
    printf("%02x ", buf[i]);
    }
    return;
    }
}
```

--------------------raw mode code------------------------

```
  #include <sys/types.h>
  #include <sys/stat.h>
  #include <fcntl.h>
  #include <termios.h>
  #include <stdio.h>

  #define BAUDRATE B9600
  #define MODEMDEVICE "/dev/ttyUSB0"
  #define _POSIX_SOURCE 1 /* POSIX compliant source */
  #define FALSE 0
  #define TRUE 1

  volatile int STOP=FALSE;

  main()
  {
    int fd,c, res;
    struct termios oldtio,newtio;
    unsigned char buf[255];

    fd = open(MODEMDEVICE, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY );
    if (fd <0) {perror(MODEMDEVICE); exit(-1); }

    tcgetattr(fd,&oldtio); /* save current port settings */

    bzero(&newtio, sizeof(newtio));
    newtio.c_cflag = BAUDRATE | CRTSCTS | CS8 | CLOCAL | CREAD;
    newtio.c_iflag = IGNPAR;
    newtio.c_oflag = 0;

    /* set input mode (non-canonical, no echo,...) */
    newtio.c_lflag = 0;

    newtio.c_cc[VTIME]    = 0;   
    newtio.c_cc[VMIN]     = 40;   

    tcflush(fd, TCIFLUSH);
    tcsetattr(fd,TCSANOW,&newtio);

    int i;
    while (STOP==FALSE) {       
      res = read(fd,buf,255);   
      for( i=0;i<res;++i){
        printf("%02x \n", buf[i]);
      }
    }
    tcsetattr(fd,TCSANOW,&oldtio);
  }
```

It now can print out the data once buffer capacity is full ( which is 40 ).
1 question:

1. When I modified the printf

   `printf("%02x ", buf[i]); ( remove "\n" )`
   It will not print out when the buffer is full until more bytes are received. Why this happens?

Thanks

Comment: What is "too long"? What makes you think the data should already be larger than 40 bytes? as far as I can tell from the code, it behaves as it's suppose to. ``read`` blocks until data is available. If your modem device is slow, then I would guess so is ``read``.

Comment: @Fred, I have a remote controller and every time I press the button it will send the command to my host through serial port. Say if I added one line of code newtio.c_cc[VEOF] = 1 and remove return in the while loop, once the button is pressed, the command display on the terminal immediately and the command size is larger than 40 bytes.

Comment: Does the situation improve whan you use `stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 raw` command?

Comment: @vlp yea, by using stty, everytime I press the button the command displays on the terminal.

Comment: Then have a look at e.g. [here](http://www.cs.uleth.ca/~holzmann/C/system/ttyraw.c) how to do the same programmatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to switch the terminal to *raw* mode to disable line buffering.

Citing [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/21760/123888):

> The terms raw and cooked only apply to terminal drivers. "Cooked" is
>   called canonical and "raw" is called non-canonical mode.
>
> The terminal driver is, by default a line-based system: characters are
>   buffered internally until a carriage return (Enter or Return) before
>   it is passed to the program - this is called "cooked". This allows
>   certain characters to be processed (see stty(1)), such as Cntl-D,
>   Cntl-S, Ctrl-U Backspace); essentially rudimentary line-editing. The
>   terminal driver "cooks" the characters before serving them up.
>
> The terminal can be placed into "raw" mode where the characters are
>   not processed by the terminal driver, but are sent straight through
>   (it can be set that INTR and QUIT characters are still processed).
>   This allows programs like emacs and vi to use the entire screen more
>   easily.
>
> You can read more about this in the "Canonical mode" section of the
>   termios(3) manpage.

See e.g. [this](http://www.cs.uleth.ca/~holzmann/C/system/ttyraw.c) or [this](http://www.minek.com/files/unix_examples/raw.html) how to achieve that programmatically (did not check the code, but it should be easy to find it).

Alternatively you could use e.g. `strace` or `ltrace` to check what `stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 raw` does (or read the manual page where it is described).

EDIT>

Regarding `printf` without a newline -- `fflush(stdout);` immediately after it should help (another line-buffering is taking place).

You might consider reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716296/why-does-printf-not-flush-after-the-call-unless-a-newline-is-in-the-format-strin) and maybe [this](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Stream-Buffering.html).

Comment: thanks. your solution works to me. however, I've updated the post and please take a look and let me know if you have any idea.